# Thunderbird 3.0 error while trying to get mail: "The folder is being processed. Please wait until processing is complete to get messages."

Tags: windows-xp, thunderbird

Just upgraded to TB3.  On opening TB i get a message 'determining which messages to index'.  After several minutes, the message disappears.  If i then try to get mail, the message quoted in the title appears.  I'm using Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

> When attempting to download your mail,
>   you may receive an error message that
>   says "This folder is being processed.
>   Please wait until processing is
>   complete to get messages." There seem
>   to be a variety of things that can
>   cause this. Some are listed below,
>   with links to threads offering further
>   details and possible fixes.
>
> - Messages with [bad headers](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=404392#404392) or header fields [left blank](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=445267#445267).
> - Checking [multiple accounts while filtering](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=233669#233669) mail between accounts.
> - For older (pre-1.0) versions of Thunderbird: simultaneously getting
>     mail for two or more accounts that use
>     the [Global Inbox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_:_FAQs_:_Global_Inbox). In Thunderbird 0.8,
>     it may be possible to [avoid this
>     problem](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=791828#791828) by clicking the "Get Mail"
>     icon in the toolbar rather than using
>     the keyboard shortcut (not yet
>     confirmed). Related information: see
>     Bugzilla [Bug 260447](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=260447).
> - Your [anti-virus software](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=445420#445420) locking up your Inbox. Also see this article
>     on [using Thunderbird with anti-virus
>     software.](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_:_FAQs_:_Anti-virus_Software)
> - You don't have permissions to read/write to your inbox. This can
>     happen when [sharing mail between linux
>     and windows](http://texturizer.net/thunderbird/share_mail.html) and the partition
>     containing your inbox has been mounted
>     with permissions higher than the user
>     running thunderbird.
> - Checking mail while [compacting folders](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_:_Tips_:_Compacting_Folders) for the account(s) being
>     checked.
> - Accidentally double clicking "Get Mail", accidentally clicking "Get
>     Mail" while trying to select an
>     account from the adjacent drop down
>     list, or the PC resuming from sleep
>     mode can cause this. There are a lot
>     of other variations, what they have in
>     common is that they're all timing
>     dependent.

[Courtesy of Mozillazine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_:_Issues_:_Folder_Being_Processed)

Answer (score 0):

I had this and went to the ISP mail server. I had 700 messages left there. I checked and then deleted the lot.

The Folder being processed error and the long email download delays stopped from that moment.

For me that was a complete and sudden solution.

Answer (score 0):

[This MozillaZine KB article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_:_Issues_:_Folder_Being_Processed) should help you.